# sql исключение из множества повторяющихся строк и значений

Tags: sql, oracle

**1. Имеется табл item**

| id | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201 | 0 |
| 1 | 555 | 2 |
| 1 | 201 | 3 |
| 1 | 202 | 0 |
| 1 | 555 | 4 |
| 2 | 201 | 0 |
| 2 | 555 | 6 |
| 2 | 201 | 0 |
| 2 | 202 | 0 |
| 2 | 555 | 0 |

**2. Задача**
Найти все id для которых одновременно справедливы ряд условий:

1. type<>555 и count=0
2. type=555 и count<>0

**3. Ожидаемый результат**

| id | type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 555 | 6 |

**4. Вариант sql query**

```
select * 
from item where id in 
  (select distinct(id) 
   from item where 
   type<>555 и count=0
  ) 
 and type=555 и count<>0
```

Возвращаются все id.
Подскажите пож-та что еще можно попробовать?

Comment: у вас по указанным условиям с таблицы `item` не совпадает только третья и последняя запись. надо уточнить как вы получили "ожидаемый результат".

Comment: В массиве данных последняя строка для id=2 не соответствует указанному правилу 2. Однако этот id должен быть возвращён... почему?

Answer (score 0):

Смущает формулировка в постановке задачи - `одновременно справедливы`... Скорее всего там должно быть что-то `одновременно удовлетворяет одному из условий`. В таком случае попробуйте так.

```sql
SELECT i.id
FROM item i
WHERE (i.type <> 555 AND i.count = 0) OR 
      (i.type = 555 AND i.count <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Найти все id для которых одновременно справедливы ряд условий:
>
> - type<>555 и count=0
> - type=555 и count<>0

Шаблон:

```
SELECT id
FROM item
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN {условие 1} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN {условие 2} THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
-- ...
```

Запрос проверяет, что для данного id отсутствуют записи, не соответствующие условиям.

Обычно условия должны быть взаимоисключающими - т.е. никакая запись не должна соответствовать более чем одному условию.

Т.е. для приведённой задачи (в ней условия как раз взаимоисключающие) будет

```
SELECT id
FROM item
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type <> 555 AND count = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN type = 555 AND count <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```